# Personalized "anthropic principle" and many-worlds divorce between Schroedinger's cats

Tags: schroedingers-cat, anthropic-principle

Anthropic principle, at least in laymen explanations that I have encountered so far, sounds something like "the physical universe suits us exceptionally well because among all the possibilities we, the observers, tautologically encounter the one that can support us."

I was wondering whether this principle can be applied to specific observers. That is, suppose that Schroedinger performs his thought experiment with himself, rather than his cat. Would the anthropic principle imply **from Schroedinger's viewpoint** that he would always survive, at least according to many-worlds interpretation?

How about this setting, assuming many-worlds interpretation: two people decided to divorce by proceeding with their lives as window&widower in separate universes. They create a setup similar with Schroedingers, except that 2 boxes have been created in such a way that a person in exactly one of them would get killed, depending how a certain superposition collapses. Then the unhappy couple enters the chambers. Does the anthropic principle imply that **each** of them would experience the exiting the chamber as the sole surviving spouse?

Comment: Terminology issue: the many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics is usually not identified as a "multiverse", with the latter term being reserved for different regions of a single space-time. That aside, yes, MWI implies both of your conclusions for those two thought experiments. The first example, of Schroedinger's cat from the cat's point of view, is usually called the [quantum suicide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_suicide_and_immortality) thought experiment.

Comment: @dgh I think that would qualify as an interesting answer if you summarised quantum suicide, which the OP, and likely many others seems not to have heard of.

Comment: It's not a particularly long or technical Wikipedia article, and the summary is essentially what OP already said.

Comment: @dgh: thanks for the link, that answer my questions.

Answer (score -1):

One interpretation of the Anthropic Principle indeed describes it that  narrowly.

You/ me in (our subjective form ) is the *only* ultimate life form. Just one central person .. the subjective.
Subjective survival=the Goldilocks zone (See also “quantum immortality”).

Here, you may subjectively *seem* to be always deteriorating , forever heading out of the Goldilocks, but it’s really the same sort of illusion as a guy tumbling down on an air current. Looks like he’s going to do himself a great mischief but never does.

Anyhow,  if you can’t seem to die..  you may get odd idea the universe was designed for you.
What *you* call *other humans* seem quite *close* to your Goldilocks zone, but no cigar ..

Let’s be honest , ***you don’t actually know any other humans.***
You know only a partial model of them, nothing like your own subjective . They are ciphers, ships that pass in the night.
There’s one and only one human in your universe.

The human echos of you are good - but they survive imperfectly.
They come and go..

Luckily new ones keep popping up, and they are intrinsic to your existence, both their presence, and their entropy-removing departure.

Almost like the cells in ‘your body’.